# SKTileDefinition Normal Texture Not Rendering Properly Outside of Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm currently making a game with Spritekit and struggling to figure out why my normalized Textures are not being applied properly when rendering on device, while they seem to be fine in the simulator.

Here is the code that adds the normal textures to the tile definitions, among other things:

```
    self.wallTileMap = self.scene?.childNode(withName: "Walls") as? SKTileMapNode
    let textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Wall Normal Maps")
    if let tileMap = self.wallTileMap {
        let startingLocation:CGPoint = tileMap.position
        let tileSize = tileMap.tileSize
        let halfWidth = CGFloat(tileMap.numberOfColumns) / 2.0 * tileSize.width
        let halfHeight = CGFloat(tileMap.numberOfRows) / 2.0 * tileSize.height
        let rows = tileMap.numberOfRows
        let columns = tileMap.numberOfColumns
        for column in 0..<columns {
            for row in 0..<rows {
                let x = CGFloat(column) * tileSize.width - halfWidth + (tileSize.width / 2)
                let y = CGFloat(row) * tileSize.height - halfHeight + (tileSize.height / 2)
                if let tileDefinition = tileMap.tileDefinition(atColumn: column, row: row) {
                    if let name = tileDefinition.name  {
                        let normalTexture = textureAtlas.textureNamed("\(name)_n")
                        tileDefinition.normalTextures = [normalTexture]
                    }
                    if (tileDefinition.userData?["shouldKill"] as? Bool ?? false) {
                        let newNode = SKShapeNode(rectOf: tileDefinition.size)
                        newNode.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
                        newNode.isHidden = true
                        newNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: tileDefinition.textures[0], size: tileDefinition.size)
                        newNode.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
                        newNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
                        newNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.wall.rawValue
                        newNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CollisionTypes.dynamicComponents.rawValue
                        newNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypes.dynamicComponents.rawValue
                        self.addChild(newNode)
                        newNode.position = CGPoint(x: newNode.position.x + startingLocation.x, y: newNode.position.y + startingLocation.y)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The result for simulator--which is expected:
[image: Game running in simulator]

The result on device--which is incorrect:
[image]

I tried multiple simulators, it worked on them all. I've also tried multiple physical devices and it was broken on all of them.

The only thing that I could find while debugging is that the normal images on device seemed to be off by one pixel in size occasionally. So the normal size is 128 x 128 and occasionally the size on device would be 128 x 127 or 127 x 127. No clue what could cause this, nor if that is the actual problem.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why the normal maps would be rendered properly in the simulator, but not on device?

Comment: SKTileMapNodes are EXTREMELY buggy. I have first-hand experience with the myriad of bugs that are riddled throughout that entire feature. It feels like a feature that was released too early and has never been worked on again.

Comment: I’ve noticed that there hasn’t been much work on SpriteKit the last couple years, which is a bit concerning. I’m wondering if I would be best to switch to another engine? Tile mapping is something I planned on relying on heavily...